# Stop Shiny DT column widths jumping when filtering a factor column

Tags: r, shiny, dt

The *Species* column in this example is factor, which DT helpfully filters with a selectize-like widget.  Only annoyance is clicking in the filter box makes the column width jump.  Does anyone know how to suppress this behaviour?

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput("data_tbl")), 
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$data_tbl <- renderDT(filter = "top", iris, 
                                options = list(autoWidth = FALSE, bAutoWidth = FALSE))
  }
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`autoWidth=TRUE` will resolve your issue.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput("data_tbl")), 
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$data_tbl <- renderDT(iris, filter = "top", 
                                options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, bAutoWidth = FALSE))
  }
)
```